# rails custom helper does not concatenate divs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-helper, helper

I have the following helper method:

```
def get_divs_for(attr)
    content_tag :div, class: 'form-group' do
      label_tag attr, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' +
      content_tag(:div, class: 'col-sm-10') do
        text_field_tag(attr,id: attr, :class => 'form-control') +
        content_tag(:span, attr, id: "message-" + attr, :class => "confirmMessage")
      end
    end
end
```

However, instead of rendering the full content:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input class="form-control" id="name" name="company[name]" type="text">
       <span id="message-name" class="confirmMessage">Name</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

I only get this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="confirmMessage" id="messageName">Name</span>
</div>
```

I tried using concatenate instead of + but got the same result.

Comment: Try using parens for this helper: `label_tag attr, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'`. So like this: `label_tag(attr, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label') +`

Comment: thanks @pdobb, but turned the same

Answer (score 1):

try

```
def get_divs_for(attr)
    content_tag :div, class: 'form-group' do
      label_tag(attr, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label') +
      content_tag(:div, class: 'col-sm-10') do
        text_field_tag(attr,id: attr, :class => 'form-control') +
        content_tag(:span, attr, id: "message-" + attr, :class => "confirmMessage")
      end
    end
end
```

it's trying to concatenate with your label class instead of label html tag

Answer (score 1):

This made it:

```
def get_divs_for(attr)
content_tag(:div, class: "form-group") do
  label_tag(attr, attr, class: "col-sm-2 control-label") +
  content_tag(:div, class: "col-sm-10") do
    text_field_tag(attr, nil, class: "form-control") +
    content_tag(:span, nil, id: "message-" + attr, class: "confirmMessage")
  end
end
```

end

Apparently it wasn't very happy with :class => 'className and prefered class: 'className'

Thanks guys for your help

Comment: I'm guessing it may have been the parenthesis, not the alternative hash construction...